# Is __proto__ an actual property of the object? [exploringjs.com]

Tags: javascript

I was reading the book [exploring js](http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_oop-besides-classes.html#_proto) and I've saw that there is mentioned that **__proto__**

> it was never an actual property:

```
var obj = {};
"__proto__" in obj //  false
```

but as I can see, if I run this code in my console, it returns **true**.

So, did the author made a mistake? Or the specs/implementations were changed meanwhile? If so, why?

Comment: From my understanding the author refers to pre-ES6 usage of `__proto__`, most browsers now support ES6, where it is a property

Comment: Speaking of "Prior to ECMAScript 6" it was not described in spec.

Comment: so you mean, that in ES5 __proto__ was not an property, and now in ES6+, it is?

Comment: Yep http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-additional-properties-of-the-object.prototype-object I mean it was not specified in spec. So it could behave any way engine implementation wants.

Comment: that's stupid simple but, the words confused me: "However, it was never an actual property"